# Where to find a summary of US FONOPS in the year 2020?

Tags: united-states, reference-request, maritime-law

Where to find a summary with dates of [FONOPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_navigation#Freedom_of_Navigation_Operations_(FONOPs)) (especially in the South China Sea) conducted by the United States in 2020 and ideally in recent years?

Some information on previous years is contained in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_navigation#FONOPs_in_the_South_China_Sea), but it is neither clear how complete it is, nor whether it is confirmed by the US.

The Annual Freedom of Navigation Reports to Congress ([example](https://policy.defense.gov/Portals/11/Documents/FY19%20DoD%20FON%20Report%20FINAL.pdf?ver=2020-07-14-140514-643&timestamp=1594749943344) for 2019) state how many “excessive claims” they have challenged (22 in 2019), but that refers to separate claims by various countries. Typically, a claim is challenged multiple times and dates and numbers on this are not furnished in the above!

Answer (score 1):

According to the U.S. Naval Institute News article titled [SECDEF Esper: U.S. Will ‘Keep Up the Pace’ of South China Sea Freedom of Navigation Operations](https://news.usni.org/2020/07/21/secdef-esper-u-s-will-keep-up-the-pace-of-south-china-sea-freedom-of-navigation-operations), dated July 21, 2020, **six freedom of navigation operations have been conducted so far in 2020.**   It also points out that in CY 2019 nine were conducted, an all-time high.

The article contains further details I think will address the remainder of your question..